# How to prevent hammer.js stop the page scrolling?

Tags: javascript, svg, hammer.js, svgpanzoom

I'm using hammer integrated with svg-pan-zoom (https://github.com/bumbu/svg-pan-zoom?tab=readme-ov-file#custom-events-support).

I would like to let the page scroll panning in vertical direction even when the touch starts over the svg.
Currently with the solution linked, the page scroll is disabled if I tap over the svg.

I tried to intercept the pan eventbut it did not helped. I tried to add `touchAction: "pan-y"` option in hammer and also `touch-action:pan-y` css property but it did not helped.